# ObjectFactory method not recognized in MapStruct mapper - troubleshooting tips

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have this entity with a single table inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorOptions(insert = false)
public abstract class Hierarchy implements Serializable {

    private HierarchyId id;

    protected Hierarchy() {
    }

    protected Hierarchy(final HierarchyId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public HierarchyId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final HierarchyId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Embeddable
    public static class HierarchyId implements Serializable {

        private User parent;
        private User child;
        private String type;

        public HierarchyId() {
        }

        public HierarchyId(final User parent, final User child, final String type) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.child = child;
            this.type = type;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        public User getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public void setParent(final User parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

        public User getChild() {
            return child;
        }

        public void setChild(final User child) {
            this.child = child;
        }

        @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, length = 1)
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(final String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

    }

}
```

I'm trying to create a mapper who can map my generic dto to one of the specific subclasses of my entity:

```
@Configuration
@Mapper
public abstract class HierarchyMapper {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Mapping(target = "id.parent.id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "id.child.id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(source = "type", target = "id.type")
    @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "afterHierarchyMapping")
    public abstract Hierarchy mapHierarchy(HierarchyDto hierarchy);

    @ObjectFactory
    public Hierarchy createHierarchy(HierarchyDto hierarchy) {
        if (SUBTYPE_A.equals(hierarchy.getType())) {
            return new SubtypeA();
        } else if (SUBTYPE_B.equals(hierarchy.getType())) {
            return new SubtypeB();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @AfterMapping
    @Named("afterHierarchyMapping")
    void afterHierarchyMapping(@MappingTarget Hierarchy hierarchy, HierarchyDto hierarchyDto) {
        hierarchy.getId()
                  .setParent(userService.getUserById(hierarchyDto.getIdParent()));
        hierarchy.getId()
                  .setChild(userService.getUserById(hierarchyDto.getIdChild()));
    }
}
```

My problem is that with this mapper, MapStrsuct is giving me an error stating that:

```
java: The return type Hierarchy is an abstract class or interface. Provide a non abstract / non interface result type or a factory method.
```

So i wonder if my @ObjectFactory is really taken into account here since it's supposed to be the factory method MapStruct is looking for.
Maybe it's something else but i don't see what it could be.

I dont think it's relevant but User is also an abstract class and if for example i remove the     @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "afterHierarchyMapping") from mapHierarchy then i get the same error but for User instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked when i removed all this lines from the mapper:

```
@Mapping(target = "id.parent.id", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "id.child.id", ignore = true)

@BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "afterHierarchieMapping")

@Named("afterHierarchieMapping")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).